# How do I prevent that empy space to form while using reactive web design?

Tags: css

[image]
[image]

I tried various solution that I found on this website.
I'm expecting to get a better response from the reactive web design.

this is my custom CSS

```
.active.home {

  visibility: hidden

    /*nasconde la casetta dell'home*/

}

footer .mg-footer-copyright p, footer .mg-footer-copyright a {

    color: #aaaed1;

  white-space: nowrap

    }

}

 header .mg-nav-widget-area-back .inner {

    width: 100%;

    padding: 90px 0;

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){

  #menu-menu.nav.navbar-nav.mr-auto{

    }

footer .mg-footer-copyright p, footer .mg-footer-copyright a {

    white-space:normal

  }

}

input[type="submit"]:hover, input[type="reset"]:hover, button:hover, input[type="submit"]:focus, input[type="reset"]:focus, button:focus {

    background: #360a01;

    border-color: #360a01;

    color: #fff;

}

h2, .h2 {

    font-size: 32px;

    line-height: 35px;

    color: black;

}

.mg-search-box .btn {

    background: #5c1203;

    border-color: #5c1203;

    color: #fff;

}

/*

.wrapper {

    background-color: black;

  CORALLO

}

*/

.mg-nav-widget-area-back .inner {

    width: 100%;

    padding: 117px 0;

}

}

.mg-nav-widget-area-back {

    background-position: center;

    background-size: cover;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}

.owl-carousel .owl-controls .owl-buttons div:hover{ 

    background: #5c1203;

    border-color: #5c1203;

    color:#fff}

.mg-breadcrumb-title h1 {

    color: #5c1203;

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){

  #menu-menu.nav.navbar-nav.mr-auto{

    }

 header .mg-nav-widget-area-back .inner {

    width: 100%;

    padding: 30px 0;

   display: none

}

    white-space:normal

  }

.mg-sidebar .mg-widget ul li:last-child {

    border: none;

  

  font-weight:bold

}

.mg-sidebar a {

    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;

  font-weight: normal

}

.widget_meta > ul > li:nth-last-child(1) {

     display: none; 

}

.widget_meta > ul > li:nth-last-child(2) {

     display: none; 

  }

@media only screen

.mg-social .info-right

  display:none

}
```